# Multiline Chain of Implications

Tags: environments, arrows

I'm new in this forum. Is it possible to create the chain of implications as shown in the image attached, in latex ? 
Thanks in advance. 
Tatin[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sXe](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551). Yes, you can do that kind of drawing with a software called TiKz.

Answer (score 2):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand*{\statement}[1]{\text{STATEMENT}\ #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={Rightarrow}]
    \statement{1} \arrow{r} & \statement{2} \arrow[out=0, in=0]{d} \\
    \statement{3} \arrow[out=180, in=180]{d} & \statement{4}\arrow{l} \\
    \statement{5} \arrow{r} & \statement{6} 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]